# How to merge bytes into a single memoryview object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of `memoryview` objects and needs to be parsed as numpy array.
I can parse a single `memoryview` object, but I can't do it using a list.

```
binaries = MyModel.objects.all().values_list('my_binary_field', flat=True)
np.frombuffer(binaries[0], dtype=np.float64)  # OK
np.frombuffer(list(binaries), dtype=np.float64)  # I can't do this
```

I don't wanna copy the bytes into a buff since they are already loaded in RAM.
There is a way o concatenate `memoryview` objects?

---

**Update**:

As mentioned, it's not possibile to concatenate `memoryview` objects into a single one, since it's contiguous by definition.
But, going to what I would like to achieve, is there a way to create a single Numpy array from bytes without copying all the memoryviews into a new buff?

Comment: Those objects are scattered around in memory.  A concatenated buffer has to be in one contiguous block.  So, no, you can't join them without copying.

Comment: @hpaulj you're right! I didn't though about that! do you know if is there a way to create a single Numpy array from bytes without copying all the memoryview?

Comment: A NumPy array has to have consistent strides, so that's not possible either. A copy will be required. You might not see where it happens, depending on how you handle it, but it will happen.

Comment: Where are those bytes located?  Do you understand how a numpy array is stored?  About its `shape`, `dtype`, `strides` and `data buffer`?

Comment: What about using `itertools.chain`?